How to correctly get the coordinates or position on a 2D matrix stored in and dinamic array in one line with no VBA
I have a formula that I manage to do what I need If I have it on 2 separate cells, but when I try to merge them it doesn't work.
Formula one looks like this:
=INDEX(Table4[MOLD],SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!N5#=MIN(ABS(TRANSPOSE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TOROW(Table4[OC '[mm']])-TOCOL(L5-(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(BDCpadgauges[#All],BDCpadgauges[[#All],[detail]]=Sheet1!E5,"no found"),2)*2*PI()))),COUNTA(Table4[MOLD]))))))*ROW(Sheet2!N5#))-ROW(N5)+1)

And the formula on Sheet2!N5# looks like this.
=ABS(TRANSPOSE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TOROW(Table4[OC '[mm']])-TOCOL(Sheet1!L5-(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(BDCpadgauges[#All],BDCpadgauges[[#All],[detail]]=Sheet1!$E$5,"no found"),2)*2*PI()))),COUNTA(Table4[MOLD]))))

If I can keep like this the calculations are done correctly, but I want to have both formulas on the same line, so I substitute Sheet2!N5# with the second formula and I get the error that the formula contains a mistake.
Maybe there is a more elegant way to get what I need?
What I end with is a table like this:



Column A
Column B




0-----
0-----


7-----
0-----



And I want to know with one formula the row where the only value is not 0
and 1 formula to know the column of the non 0 value.
I need that everything can be contained in a non dynamic formula, because I plan to copy this formula down so I can this calculation multiple times.
I tried this on the formula with an error:
=INDEX(Table4[MOLD],SUMPRODUCT((ABS(TRANSPOSE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TOROW(Table4[OC '[mm']])-TOCOL($L$5-(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(BDCpadgauges[#All],BDCpadgauges[[#All],[detail]]=Sheet1!$E$5,"no found"),2)*2*PI()))),COUNTA(Table4[MOLD]))))=MIN(ABS(TRANSPOSE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TOROW(Table4[OC '[mm']])-TOCOL(L5-(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(BDCpadgauges[#All],BDCpadgauges[[#All],[detail]]=Sheet1!E5,"no found"),2)*2*PI()))),COUNTA(Table4[MOLD]))))))*ROW(ABS(TRANSPOSE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TOROW(Table4[OC '[mm']])-TOCOL($L$5-(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(BDCpadgauges[#All],BDCpadgauges[[#All],[detail]]=Sheet1!$E$5,"no found"),2)*2*PI()))),COUNTA(Table4[MOLD]))))))-ROW(N5)+1)

The error shown is

There's a Problem with this formula...

And do not let me do anything until I reverse it to the previews state or hit Esc.
PD: I'm feeling I'm so close, but not sure what detail I'm missing.
I'm fearful new on using dynamic arrays, but not bad on doing some matrix data.
Thanks for your help.
If more data is needed let me know.

How do you expect the output to look like? Also it's a bit unclear what you're trying to pull. Do you want to lookup the first row containing a non-0 value in combination with a zero value and return the column (number/header?) of the zero value in that row and the column of the non zero value in that row. So B & A for the second row containing values.

Hi, what I found is I can use only one of hte coordinates at a time, so IF I can get with one formula the row where the value is non 0, and then with a different one the column number where the row is not 0 that will be enougth.
The row number to me represent a point where the calculation is optimal and the column represent when it was optimal, so then I use an index in the base table to find the data related to those cases.

So do you think a sample of 4 cells and its headers represent the problem you have?
